# public static class data will same for all user in ASp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, static

In shopping cart ,i stored cart data to public static class.

is it stored cart data separate for all other clients?

or i try to check other option for storing cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contents of static class in asp.net will be **same** for all the clients. You should store items into session or any other storage depending on your requirements (may be persistent storage like database if you need to)

Answer (score 1):

> is it stored cart data separate for all other clients?

No. All clients are sharing the same cart. Never store any data in a static class that you need to be user specific. You could use the session for that.